# What is evil about announced git push -f while everybody else does git pull --rebase

Tags: git, push, git-rebase, pull

Let's say

- you forked a project on a github
- multiple people (less than 5) are working on this fork
- the goal is to make a pull request with our changes

After a few commits to our fork, we now want to update our fork to the latest HEAD from the source project.  Because multiple people are working on this fork the standard way is to pull down the source project, then do a merge commit to bring in the latest HEAD from the source project.

We don't like this because it makes our history non-linear and we will have many "useless" merge commits.

Our alternative idea is to:

1. git pull --rebase to make the local has the latest forked HEAD
2. rebase our fork to bring in the new latest HEAD source such that our commits are after the source HEAD
3. git push --force
4. everybody else will get the latest with git pull --rebase (which we can make default for everybody)

History is linear, just took some coordination for committers of the fork.

What are the problems with this approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You start here (`U` is upstream, `Y` is yours):

```
UB--U1--U2
 \
   Y1--Y2
```

Now you do a rebase (and `push -f`):

```
UB--U1--U2--Y1'--Y2'
```

Now your other team-member does `pull --rebase`:

```
UB--U1--U2--Y1'--Y2'--Y1''--Y2''
```

As robinst pointed out – if you had to resolve conflicts, git won’t notice that
there are already versions of `Y1` and `Y2` in the repo and just rebase again
(probably giving some ugly conflicts, too).

I would just recommend doing merges (you can look at your linear history with
`git log --no-merges`). If you really want to try the rebasing way, here’s what
you can do:

You run:

```
git fetch --all
git branch rebase_base master
git push origin rebase_base
git rebase upstream/master
git push -f origin master
```

Everybody else then runs:

```
git fetch origin
git rebase --onto origin/master origin/rebase_base master
```

Have a look at `git help rebase` as to why this works ;). Basically you are telling git up until which commit you already did the rebase (`rebase_base`), so it won’t rebase stuff that doesn’t need it.

Comment: instead of a rebase-base branch, couldn't one also use a rebase-base tag?

Comment: Kind of, but then this will only work once or cause trouble by itself, because changing a tag is also not that easy :).

Comment: True. Though if someone at some point decides that even the rebase_base should diverge you'll have a rebase_base_rebase_base :-7

Comment: And the answer is: stop rebasing everything :). Just to clarify: I do not support using a workflow like the one I presented in any way – I just answered the question.

Comment: Indeed it shouldn't be done without good reasons (e.g. accidental leaking of confidential data), and if these reasons occur regularly [somewhere, something went terribly wrong.](http://www.sinz.org/Michael.Sinz/Evolution.html)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `git push -f`. Rebase and merge ( via `git pull --rebase` and `git pull` respectively ) are two alternatives, and you can follow either one to keep your branch updated with upstream.

Do `git pull --rebase`, resolve conflicts if any, enjoy "useless" merge commit free history and just do `git push`

Comment: I don't think you understood the question. OP is talking about pushing a rebased branch to a shared repository, not only rebasing local commits.

Answer (score 1):

In case you have to resolve conflicts when doing the rebase in step 2, step 4 may not work without problems for others.

The reason is that Git detects whether a commit is already applied by comparing commits via their patch ID (see [git patch-id](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-patch-id)). Because of doing changes to resolve a conflict, the patch ID may change.

So manual work may be required by others, e.g. resetting and cherry-picking local changes.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, there's nothing evil about git push -f to your own branch. The bad part happens when you have to coordinate with other developers. Unless everyone is communicating at **the exact moment** that you're doing the force push, it can get complicated. To avoid complications, every developer has to stop doing the work that they're doing in order to accomodate a force push. It disrupts workflow and ends up costing unnecessary time and effort.

The nice thing about a distributed version control system is that you don't need to ask developers to stop doing their work in order to accomodate an edit! In the bad-old days, when developer(a) checked out a file, the VCS system would obtain a pessimistic lock on the file, and the other developer(b) would have to go scrambling to find the first developer(a) who checked out the file and ask that developer(a) to check in the file so that developer(b) could edit the file. But I'm getting off topic.

Back on to the topic, I think you would benefit from using a [topic branch workflow](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Branching-Workflows). Set up the `master` branch in your fork to track the original work that you've forked off of. Master contains all of the work from the original project.

As your team develops new features, they will need to merge changes somewhere. It's not uncommon to create a new remote branch named `development` or whatever you choose so the team can push/pull their changes. This new remote branch is effectively the `trunk` branch for your team.

Someone needs to be responsible for merging changes from the original project's `master` into the forked project's `development` branch, but that's a lot easier than asking everyone to accomodate a force push to the trunk. You also need to set policies for the forked project's master and development branches. This workflow allows developers to pull/merge the forked repository without interrupting their own workflow.